# Where is the settings stored for ExpressQuantumGrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I am using Express Quantum Grid from developer express. From code i came to know that they are storing the user settings using TMemIniFile. I know the sections where they are storing but is there any way to open the Ini file and see the contents? If so where is the file located?

Comment: You are using cxPropertiesStore? The file would be the StorageName e.g. `C:\temp\StoreMe.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From code I came to know that they are storing the user settings using `TMemIniFile`.

The constructor of `TMemIniFile` receives the name of the file that stores the INI file. So, you simply need to find the call to `TMemIniFile.Create` and your answer will be revealed.